# Problem with ICO smart contract on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, ropsten, ico

I hope you are all well.
I have a problem with an ICO smart contract.
I have deployed this smart contract on ropsten and when I send ethers to the smart contract I get an error message which says “out of gas” but I have enough gas.

Here are the smart contract and the ropsten informations:[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

interface ERC20Interface {
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract ERC20Token is ERC20Interface {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowed;
    
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint8 _decimals,
        uint _totalSupply)
        public {
            name = _name;
            symbol = _symbol;
            decimals = _decimals;
            totalSupply = _totalSupply;
            balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        }
        
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        uint allowance = allowed[from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= value && allowance >= value);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[to] += value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(spender != msg.sender);
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns(uint) {
        return allowed[owner][spender];
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
}

contract ICO {
    struct Sale {
        address investor;
        uint quantity;
    }
    Sale[] public sales;
    mapping(address => bool) public investors;
    address public token;
    address public admin;
    uint public end;
    uint public price;
    uint public availableTokens;
    uint public minPurchase;
    uint public maxPurchase;
    bool public released;
    
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint8 _decimals,
        uint _totalSupply)
        public {
        token = address(new ERC20Token(
            _name,
            _symbol,
            _decimals,
            _totalSupply
        ));
        admin = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function start(
        uint duration,
        uint _price,
        uint _availableTokens,
        uint _minPurchase,
        uint _maxPurchase)
        external
        onlyAdmin() 
        icoNotActive() {
        require(duration > 0, 'duration should be > 0');
        uint totalSupply = ERC20Token(token).totalSupply();
        require(_availableTokens > 0 && _availableTokens <= totalSupply, 'totalSupply should be > 0 and <= totalSupply');
        require(_minPurchase > 0, '_minPurchase should > 0');
        require(_maxPurchase > 0 && _maxPurchase <= _availableTokens, '_maxPurchase should be > 0 and <= _availableTokens');
        end = duration + now; 
        price = _price;
        availableTokens = _availableTokens;
        minPurchase = _minPurchase;
        maxPurchase = _maxPurchase;
    }
    
    function whitelist(address investor)
        external
        onlyAdmin() {
        investors[investor] = true;    
    }
    
    function buy()
        payable
        external
        onlyInvestors()
        icoActive() {
        require(msg.value % price == 0, 'have to send a multiple of price');
        require(msg.value >= minPurchase && msg.value <= maxPurchase, 'have to send between minPurchase and maxPurchase');
        uint quantity = price * msg.value;
        require(quantity <= availableTokens, 'Not enough tokens left for sale');
        sales.push(Sale(
            msg.sender,
            quantity
        ));
    }
    
    function release()
        external
        onlyAdmin()
        icoEnded()
        tokensNotReleased() {
        ERC20Token tokenInstance = ERC20Token(token);
        for(uint i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
            Sale storage sale = sales[i];
            tokenInstance.transfer(sale.investor, sale.quantity);
        }
    }
    
    function withdraw(
        address payable to,
        uint amount)
        external
        onlyAdmin()
        icoEnded()
        tokensReleased() {
        to.transfer(amount);    
    }

    function fallback() payable external {}
    
    modifier icoActive() {
        require(end > 0 && now < end && availableTokens > 0, "ICO must be active");
        _;
    }
    
    modifier icoNotActive() {
        require(end == 0, 'ICO should not be active');
        _;
    }
    
    modifier icoEnded() {
        require(end > 0 && (now >= end || availableTokens == 0), 'ICO must have ended');
        _;
    }
    
    modifier tokensNotReleased() {
        require(released == false, 'Tokens must NOT have been released');
        _;
    }
    
    modifier tokensReleased() {
        require(released == true, 'Tokens must have been released');
        _;
    }
    
    modifier onlyInvestors() {
        require(investors[msg.sender] == true, 'only investors');
        _;
    }
    
    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == admin, 'only admin');
        _;
    }
    
}
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Since your ICO contract has a `payable` fallback function, it gets called when you send the contract Ethers. And your transaction's *gas limit* is 21000, which means there is zero gas left for the contract to perform operations, and therefore the transactions runs out of gas.

Increase your gas limit, if you intended to call the fallback function.